# Speeding up terra::patches() for large raster

Tags: r, terra

I have a heterogeneous land cover change raster as shown below. I want to run `terra::patches()` on it to detect where change occurred. For example, most of the cells are 0, but there are many sporadic cells that are > 0 or < 0 indicating change from a previous state.

My problem is that `patches()` runs incredibly slowly, and I'm not sure if there's any way to make it faster. I don't think I can break up the raster into smaller chunks because then the patch IDs are discontinuous. Any advice?

```
> chm_layer
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5200, 5671, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 624080, 629751, 1009717, 1014917  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N (EPSG:32617) 
source(s)   : memory
name        : DSM_2020_corrected 
min value   :          -50.49600 
max value   :           39.31499
```

The code I'm using is from the `getForestGaps` function in the `ForestGapR` package.

```
threshold <- -5
chm_layer[chm_layer > threshold] <- NA
chm_layer[chm_layer <= threshold] <- 1
gaps <- terra::patches(chm_layer, directions = 4, allowGaps = FALSE)
```

Running `patches()` as is takes > 10 minutes to run. I don't know exactly how long because I killed the process.